# require.extensions is not supported by webpack. Use a loader instead

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, webpack, ejs

I use `express` + `webpack3` + `ejs` + `typescript`

when I build, the `stdout` output give me some warning:

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js
require.extensions is not supported by webpack. Use a loader instead.
 @ ./src/environment.ts 4:10-24
 @ ./src/server.ts

WARNING in ./node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js
require.extensions is not supported by webpack. Use a loader instead.
 @ ./src/environment.ts 4:10-24
 @ ./src/server.ts

WARNING in ./node_modules/express/lib/view.js
80:29-41 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
```

here is part of `webpack.config.ts`:

```
import * as webpack from 'webpack';
import * as path from 'path';
import * as CopyWebpackPlugin from 'copy-webpack-plugin';

const config: webpack.Configuration = {
  target: 'node',
  devtool: 'source-map',
  entry: {
    server: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/server.ts')
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: 'server.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'ts-loader'
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js']
  },
  plugins: [
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      { from: './src/views', to: 'views' },
      { from: './src/public', to: 'public' }
    ])
  ]
};

export default config;
```

and part of `tsconfig.json`:

```
"include": [
    "src/server.ts",
    "src/typings"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "src/public",
    "src/views"
  ]
```

Comment: did you have this problem fixed?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and I solved it by adding the following code to my webpack.config.js file:

```
resolve: {
   alias: {
       'express-handlebars': 'handlebars/dist/handlebars.js'
   }
}
```

Comment: This is not relevant to the question's setup as it's not using handlebars.

Comment: Hi Yangshun! I got your point, but I just shared what worked for me. ;)

Comment: @MarioMinondo glad you decided to post this, because I had exact same problem!

Answer (score 5):

The best solution for this is using [webpack-node-externals](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-node-externals) to not worry about node_modules at all when working with webpack for backend.

> When bundling with Webpack for the backend - you usually don't want to bundle its node_modules dependencies. This library creates an externals function that ignores node_modules when bundling in Webpack.

Answer (score 2):

This set up uses `ejs` and the `ejs`-specific solution is to set this in your webpack config:

```
resolve: {
   alias: {
     'ejs': 'ejs.min.js'
   }
}
```

Comment: Should this be `ejs/ejs.min.js`?